# Obtaining the eta2 table provided in the FactoMineR package

Tags: r, correlation, pca

I'm using FactoMineR to perform PCA on a biological dataset, where each column is a gene and the rows contain different samples. The samples belong to different groups (control/treatment; cancer/noncancer). I've included this information as qualitative supplements when applying the PCA() function, and I sort of understand that when we call $quali.sup$eta2, we get a table with the squared correlations between each categorical variable and the principal components. My question is: how is that table exactly obatined -- how is the correlation exactly calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlation (squared) is computed between the coordinates of the samples (individuals in FactoMineR terms) and the categorical variable **expressed as numeric factor levels**.

Answer (score 1):

The package [vingette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FactoMineR/FactoMineR.pdf) on p41 identifies `eta2` as the correlation coefficient.

The correlation coefficient is be based on the underlying correlation matrices.

The exact methodology should be within the reference that the package author provides.  Methods for producing eigenvalues and eigenvectors are usually where packages differ but the matrix algebra is generally the same.

> Husson, F., Le, S. and Pages, J. (2010). Exploratory Multivariate Analysis by Example Using R,
>   Chapman and Hall.